# Google Apps Script! How to determine current user editing cell in SpreadSheet

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I need to determine current user editing cell in SpreadSheet
Is it possible?

if i use
**Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()**
it is return empty string

From documentation:

> If security policies do not allow access to the user's identity,
>   User.getEmail() returns a blank string

How manage security policies?

Comment: See [Authorization for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization)

Comment: You can only get the email if all users are under the same domain and you set a installable on edit trigger.